# Dropbox API - What happen if there is no internet connection

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Hi I develop an app with dropbox support.

I complete the authentication and everything working fine.

When I switch off internet connection and I try to upload files I receive success callback...!!!

After that if I switch on internet nothing happens.

Is this the way things must happen or I am wrong somewhere??

Here is the code I use for upload

```
            FileInputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            File file = new File("/path to my file.txt");

            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);


            Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFileOverwrite("/path to my file.txt", inputStream, file.length(), null);

            Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: perhaps it is throwing an Exception type that you are not handling...i typically throw in a `catch (Exception e)` as a catch-all. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() 
{
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
    {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;

}
```

use the above method to check whether there is internet connection is available or not. so that you can check and display toast message if internet connection is available

if you use this method then don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

to your manifest file